# Updating a Bulky mySQL query for active users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a long form PHP function to loop over all my users and test their activity status. It's slow and takes multiple operations... this SQL operation is much faster but right now but my counts mismatch with each other.

I need to update this mySQL query to do what it does with 1 addition and 1 adjustment. So that it mimics the exact action/function of testing user activity.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT last.user_id
FROM ss_usermeta as last
JOIN ss_usermeta as next on last.user_id = next.user_id
WHERE last.meta_key = 'last_trans_date' and last.meta_value <= CURDATE()
and next.meta_key = 'next_recurring_date' and next.meta_value + INTERVAL 9 day >= CURDATE()";
```

- Check each users meta_key for 'll_customer_id' and make sure its not empty.
- Change the comparator of the next_recurring_date from the current date to the current date + 9 days.

Comment: Not sure if I am making progress by myself... but i've updated it to do the + 9 days thing... the 9 days is supposed to be added to the value of the 'next_recurring_date'

 ``` 
SELECT DISTINCT last.user_id
 FROM ss_usermeta as last
 JOIN ss_usermeta as next on last.user_id = next.user_id
 WHERE last.meta_key = 'last_trans_date' and last.meta_value <= CURDATE()
 and next.meta_key = 'next_recurring_date' and next.meta_value + INTERVAL 9 day >= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another join for this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT last.user_id
FROM ss_usermeta as last
JOIN ss_usermeta as next
  on last.user_id = next.user_id
JOIN ss_usermeta as third
  on third.user_id = next.user_id
WHERE last.meta_key = 'last_trans_date'
  and last.meta_value <= CURDATE()
and next.meta_key = 'next_recurring_date'
  and next.meta_value + INTERVAL 9 day >= CURDATE()
and third.meta_key = 'll_customer_id'
  and third.meta_value is not null;
```

Comment: Thank you so much the count is off by 10 but this has dramatically improved the accuracy of my function. I'm going to continue to re-evaluate how I handle the activity status of my users.